# iOS Fill half of UIBezierPath with other color without CAGradientLayer

Tags: swift, uiscrollview, slider, uibezierpath, curve

I have a question about drawing half of a `UIBezierPath`. How do I fill left part (left from thumb) with green color and right part (right from thumb) with white color without using `CAGradientLayer`?

Code I used to create Bezier Path - https://gist.github.com/robertmryan/67484c74297cede3926a3aed2fceedb9

Screenshot of what I want to achieve:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One approach is to add a mask layer to your curved-path shape layer.

When the "thumb" position changes, change the width of the mask to reveal only the "left-side" of the shape layer.

Create a shape layer to use as the mask:

```
let maskLayer: CALayer = {
    let layer = CALayer()
    layer.backgroundColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
    return layer
}()
```

In `viewDidLoad()` set that layer as the mask for the curved-shape layer:

```
pathLayer.mask = maskLayer
```

Whenever the "thumb" position is set, update the width of the mask:

```
func updateMask(at point: CGPoint) -> Void {
    var f = view.bounds
    f.size.width = point.x
    CATransaction.begin()
    CATransaction.setDisableActions(true)
    maskLayer.frame = f
    CATransaction.commit()
}
```

I posted a modified version of your gist at: https://gist.github.com/DonMag/a2154e70a3c67193a7b19bee41c8fe95

It really has only a few changes... look for comments beginning with `// DonMag -`

Here is the result (with an imageView behind it to show the transparency):

[image]

---

**Edit**

After comments, the goal is to have the "right-side" of the track path be white instead of transparent.

Using the same approach, we can add a **white** shape layer on top of the original shape layer, and mask it to show only the right-hand-side.

Here is an updated gist - https://gist.github.com/DonMag/397dfbe4779e817531ef7a663365b2e7 - showing this result:

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much @DonMag, this is what I was searching. But, I can't find the unselected (white) part (from the right of the thumb), and currently it is opaque. What is the problem? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: @MichaelGrigoryan - not sure what you mean? I added a screen-cap with an imageView behind to show the result.

Comment: In image you have attached I can see left blue line but no right line, which you can see in screenshot I have attached (in purple square).

Comment: @MichaelGrigoryan - ah... I thought from your image you wanted the remaining part to be hidden (transparent). I'll make some edits...